# FieldIndexOption not applied to nested objects

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I am using ElasticSearch and NEST version 2 to index data.  My data object can have child objects of the same type.  I am using annotations to indicate not to analyze certain fields.  What is happening is this annotation gets applied to the parent object, but not the children.  I am trying to figure out how to modify my annotations to include the child instances.

I have something like this:

```
public class Person {
    public int Id {get; set;}

    [String(Index = FieldIndexOption.NotAnalyzed)]
    public string Code {get; set;}

    public Person child {get; set;}
}
```

When I first create the index as follows:

```
client.Map<Person>(d => d.AutoMap());
```

The mapping looks like this:

```
"people": {
    "mappings": {
        "person": {
            "properties": {
                "id": {
                    "type": "integer"
                },
                "code": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "index": "not_analyzed"
                },
                "child": {
                    "type": "object"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

After I index some documents as follows:

```
client.Index(person);
```

the mapping changes to this:

```
"people": {
    "mappings": {
        "person": {
            "properties": {
                "id": {
                    "type": "integer"
                },
                "code": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "index": "not_analyzed"
                },
                "child": {
                    "properties": {
                        "id": {
                            "type": "integer"
                        },
                        "code": {
                            "type": "string"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Say I have a document like this:

```
{
    "id": 100,
    "code": "ABC100",
    "child": {
        "id": 123,
        "code": "ABC123"
    }
}
```

What happens is the Code field on the top-level person is not analyzed, which is good, so I can do a search like this:

```
GET people/_search
{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "code": "ABC100"
    }
  }
}
```

But the code field on the child is analyzed using the default analyzer, so ABC123 becomes abc123.

Thus, all of these will find my document:

```
GET people/_search
{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "child.id": 123
    }
  }
}
GET people/_search
{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "child.code": "abc123"
    }
  }
}
GET people/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "child.id": "ABC123"
    }
  }
}
```

But this does not:

```
GET people/_search
{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "child.code": "ABC123"
    }
  }
}
```

What change do I need to make to my object annotations in order to have the same field options applied to the child person?  (BTW, in real life I have several fields that are not analyzed, and several levels of depth.)

Comment: Can you show the mapping you get with `curl -XGET localhost:9200/people`?

Comment: Edited my question to include this info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Automapping in NEST does not recurse further than the top level by default](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/auto-map.html#mapping-recursion), so the child property on `Person` gets mapped as an object, with dynamic mapping and field type inference creating the fields on `child` in the mapping when you index a document.

NEST can recursively map types by passing a depth parameter to `.AutoMap(int)`

```
client.Map<Person>(m => m.AutoMap(1));
```

which will result in the following mapping

```
{
  "properties": {
    "id": {
      "type": "integer"
    },
    "code": {
      "type": "string",
      "index": "not_analyzed"
    },
    "child": {
      "properties": {
        "id": {
          "type": "integer"
        },
        "code": {
          "type": "string",
          "index": "not_analyzed"
        },
        "child": {
          "properties": {},
          "type": "object"
        }
      },
      "type": "object"
    }
  }
}
```

We now get `id` and `code` mapped on the child object with the expected field mapping settings. We also get a `child` field on `child`, mapped as `object`.

If you know that the depth will only ever be 1, we can tidy the mapping up slightly if we don't want the `child` field on the `child` of the top level, by using fluent mapping

```
client.Map<Person>(m => m
    .AutoMap()
    .Properties(p => p
        .Object<Person>(o => o
            .Name(n => n.child)
            .Properties(pp => pp
                .Number(n => n
                    .Name(nn => nn.Id)
                    .Type(NumberType.Integer)
                )
                .String(s => s
                    .Name(n => n.Code)
                    .NotAnalyzed()
                )
            )
        )
    )
);
```

which yields

```
{
  "properties": {
    "id": {
      "type": "integer"
    },
    "code": {
      "type": "string",
      "index": "not_analyzed"
    },
    "child": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "id": {
          "type": "integer"
        },
        "code": {
          "type": "string",
          "index": "not_analyzed"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```